# Issues with Store Certification regarding Nuget package

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, windows-store-apps

My last submission to the store failed because of a WACK failure. The issue seems to be related to the Microsoft.Toolkit.UWP.UI.Lottie package. Previous submission referenced this package and had no problem, though this is my first submission targeting 1903 and min version 1809.

I already cleaned all cached files such as .vs, bin and obj folder. re-installed lottie file and still get the same problem. Local WACK gives me the same error.

Here is the error log they sent me:

```
Parameter value of method add_AnimatedVisualInvalidated of type Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Lottie.ILottieVisualSourceClass in file Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Lottie.winmd references the non-Windows Runtime type Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls.IDynamicAnimatedVisualSource. Windows Runtime types can reference only Windows Runtime types.
The type Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls.IAnimatedVisual referenced by type Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Lottie.ILottieVisualSourceClass in file Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Lottie.winmd was not found. All types referenced in metadata files must be discoverable.
Parameter value of method add_AnimatedVisualInvalidated of type Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Lottie.LottieVisualSource in file Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Lottie.winmd references the non-Windows Runtime type Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls.IDynamicAnimatedVisualSource. Windows Runtime types can reference only Windows Runtime types.
The type Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls.IAnimatedVisual referenced by type Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Lottie.LottieVisualSource in file Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Lottie.winmd was not found. All types referenced in metadata files must be discoverable.
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you re-associate your package before package the app?Did you use the latest version of Microsoft.Toolkit.UWP.UI.Lottie package?